# Write into NSMutableArray from NSString

Tags: iphone

i want to write NSString into NSMutableArray.Please look at the following code:

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil        error:nil];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
returnString = [returnString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(returnString);
```

Here i get some response(a plist file) from a server which i saved as NSData and then convert it to NSString.When i print this NSString it looks like following.

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<string>sourav sas</string>
<string>dipto pol</string>
<string>Shahriar Alam</string>
<string>toukir naim</string>
<string>shamim mohiuddin</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Now i want to copy this NSString into an NSMutableArray.Each index of NSMutable array will contain the names between  tag. How can i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data
                                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers 
                                                                   format:NULL 
                                                         errorDescription:NULL];
```

Comment: You mean i can convert NSData directly to NSMutable Array?

Comment: Yes, you can. Take a look at documentation about `NSPropertyListSerialization`. `Property list programming guide` is also very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use NSXMLParser. See this tutorial:

http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html